# AlamofireImage on-disk persistent cache

Tags: caching, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm using AlamofireImage to download images from the web. 
But when i use the images later it downloads the images again and it don't work if my app is offline. Is there a way to save the downloaded images from the web in my app?

This is the code i use:

```
imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL, placeholderImage: nil, imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.25))
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

The headers from the image request had no cache policy.